# What's the difference between Lorentz transformation properties of Hermitian and Dirac adjoint lepton doublets?

Tags: special-relativity, dirac-matrices, leptons

If the lepton doublet transforms like a left-handed Weyl spinor under Lorentz transformations,
$$
L \longrightarrow exp\left[\frac{1}{2}(i\theta_j\sigma^j - \beta_j\sigma^j)\right]L = \Lambda_{sL}L,
$$
then does the Hermitian adjoint transform like
$$
L^\dagger \longrightarrow (\Lambda_{sL}L)^\dagger = L^\dagger\Lambda_{sL}^\dagger = L^\dagger exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(i\theta_j\sigma^j + \beta_j\sigma^j)\right] = L^\dagger\Lambda_{sR}^{-1}?
$$
How does the Dirac adjoint lepton then transform? I've tried
$$
\overline{L} \longrightarrow (\Lambda_{sL}L)^\dagger\gamma^0 = L^\dagger\Lambda_{sR}^{-1}\gamma^0.
$$
$\Lambda_{sR}^{-1}$ and $\gamma^0$ aren't the same dimensions, so do they commute? Do I then get
$$
\overline{L} \longrightarrow \overline{L}\Lambda_{sR}^{-1},
$$
such that theres no difference between the transformation properties of Hermitian adjoint and Dirac adjoint lepton doublets?

Answer (score 1):

$$(\Lambda)^\dagger \neq \Lambda^{-1}$$
instead
$$\gamma^0(\Lambda)^\dagger \gamma^0 =  \Lambda^{-1}$$

Comment: Isn't that only true for the whole $\Lambda_s = exp[i\theta_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}]$?

Comment: Lorentz transformation is chirality preserving. So the properties I mentioned are true regardless whether you are talking about the chiral Weyl spinor or the whole Dirac spinor.